# Pause FileIO.FileSystem.CopyFile c#

Tags: c#, file-io, copy

Hello fellow programmers! I have this specific method right here that copies a file from a source to a destination. I am trying to figure out how to pause the method without having to press the pause button within the dialog. Is this possible?

```
 public static void CopyFileInDirectory(string source, string dest, ThreadFinishedCallback callback)
    {
        Threadfinished = callback;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dest);
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(source)) //cycle trough all files in the folder
        {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyFile(f, Path.Combine(dest, Path.GetFileName(f)), UIOption.AllDialogs, UICancelOption.ThrowException);
                //Trying to pause this
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong while trying to copy the file: "+ f);
            }
        }
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(source))
        {
            string targetDirectory = dest +@"\"+ Path.GetFileName(d);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDirectory);
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(d, targetDirectory, UIOption.AllDialogs);
            //Trying to pause this
        }
        DeleteFilesInDirectory(source);
        Threadfinished?.Invoke(currentTask);
    }
```

Comment: Does `CopyFileInDirectory` run on a separate thread (guessing no)?

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes it runs in a custom "threadpool" class i found on internet and edited so i can pause the threads. But it does not pause the copy, it only pauses after the copy is finished, therefore the resources are still being used. That is why I want to pause the copy itself.

Comment: Using the API to copy files means you are telling the OS to copy. There is no way to pause in the middle of a copy operation. In order to do that, you'll have to write your own copy operation that is pausable/resumable.

Comment: @RonBeyer Then there is no way to tell the api to pause its action?